# Fiber prodcut of schemes, confusion with the definition of a gluing datum

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof of the existence of fiber products for a scheme in Görtz/Wedhorn, there is a step where we assume that for an open covering $X=\bigcup_iU_i$ the fiber products $Z_i=U_i\times_SY$ exist, and we want to show that then also $X\times_SY$ exists. Denoting by $p_i:Z_i\rightarrow U_i$ and $q_i:Z_i\rightarrow Y$ the first and second projections, respectively, we define a gluing datum by  setting first $Z_{ij}=p_i^{-1}(U_i\cap U_j)$ and letting $p_{ij}$ be the restriction of $p_i$ to $Z_{ij}$. Then both $Z_{ij}$ and $Z_{ji}$ are a fiber product of $U_i\cap U_j$ and $Y$ over $S$ and hence there is a unique isomorphism $\varphi_{ij}:Z_{ij}\rightarrow Z_{ji}$ with $p_{ji}\circ \varphi_{ij}=p_{ij}$. The uniqueness implies $\varphi_{ji}=\varphi_{ij}^{-1}$, that's what I still see. However, it is being said that the uniqueness implies the cocycle relation, and this I don't see. After all, I think uniqueness here is a property of maps $Z_{ij}\rightarrow Z_{ji}$? And the cocycle-relation needs to be checked on intersections like $Z_{ij}\cap Z_{ik}$, so I don't know how I can deduce here, and I would be glad for any kind of hint.

Comment: The idea, if I recall correctly, is that $Z_{ij} \cap Z_{jk}$ is a fiber product for $U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Mindlack, and then $Z_{ki}\cap Z_{kj}$ is also a fiber product for $U_i\cap U_j\cap U_k$ and $Y$ over $S$, so they are uniquely isomorphic and both $\varphi_{ik}$ and $\varphi_{kj}\circ\varphi_{ij}$ properly restricted to so, so they must be equal?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the crux of the argument.